# Reading and writing two-dimensional array to file

Tags: c#, arrays, binaryfiles

I get a 2D array from a device at specific time intervals. I keep these series in a list. I need to write the sequences in the list to the file on the computer. After reading these series
I will put it in the list again. I found a method for this. I can write the series. I have some questions at the point of reading.

When I write a fixed array; Example `short[,] array2D = new short[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };`

I read it properly when I want to read the same series knowing its dimensions.

But when I write more than one series in a row, I want to read it piece by piece. I failed on this. How can I read the sequences from the file?

Write Code

```
private void testWriteArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<Globals.logArrayList.Count; i++)
        {
            array2D = Globals.logArrayList[i];

            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
            BinaryWriter writeBinary = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);
            GCHandle arrHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array2D, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr arrPtr = arrHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            unsafe
            {
                int arrLen = array2D.Length;
                if (arrLen > 0)
                {
                    IEnumerator enumerator = array2D.GetEnumerator();
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                    int arrSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(enumerator.Current) * arrLen;

                    using (UnmanagedMemoryStream arrStream =
                    new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)arrPtr.ToPointer(), arrSize))
                    {
                        arrStream.CopyTo(writeBinary.BaseStream, (int)arrStream.Length);
                    }
                }
            }

            arrHandle.Free();

            writeStream.Flush();
            writeStream.Close();

        }
    }
```

Read Code

```
   static Array testReadArray()
    {

        int[,] array2D = new int[1000, 2000];

        FileStream readStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryWriter readBinary = new BinaryWriter(readStream);
        GCHandle arrHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array2D, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr arrPtr = arrHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        unsafe
        {
            int arrLen = array2D.Length;
            if (arrLen > 0)
            {
                IEnumerator enumerator = array2D.GetEnumerator();
                enumerator.MoveNext();
                int arrSize =
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(enumerator.Current) * arrLen;

                using (UnmanagedMemoryStream arrStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream
                ((byte*)arrPtr.ToPointer(), arrSize, arrSize, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    readBinary.BaseStream.CopyTo(arrStream, (int)arrStream.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        arrHandle.Free();
        readStream.Close();
        return array2D;
    }
```

In the reading code, I don't know how many dimensions the array is in the file. That's why I gave the array size 1000,2000. Normally, although my data is between 0-255, I am reading 6-7 digit numbers while reading.

Is it possible for me to know the number of strings in the file? If so how?

Comment: You could just read it line by line and extract the numbers from that line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: When reading you need to be able to determine the size of each chunk.  If all the chunks are the same size then there is no issue.  You read until you get EOF.  If chunks are different sizes you need a length or type before each chunk so you can determine the size of a chunk.

Comment: @TobyB : Lines do not work with binary data.  What is the End Of line for binary???  Unless each chunk of binary data has a unique determinating character than is not part of the data your solution will not work.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments. The problem is very simple, I explained the solution below.

Comment: I have a header at the beginning and end of each data packet. So I will divide the data I read into chunks this way.

Comment: This seems overbaked. Do you know how many dimension in the arrays you are reading ?

Comment: I would recommend prefixing serialized arrays with the length, or lengt*s* in this case. Even if you have a fixed size you might at one point want to change the size, and then it is very helpful to not have to change the serialization format.

Comment: Thank you @00110001 Each package I write is 48 * 64 in size, but at the time of writing it is not clear how many such packages will be written. Maybe 100 maybe 10000. So in the first run phase, I will correct this as my array size in the reading is 1000 * 2000.

Comment: @JonasH I don't quite understand what you mean. What do you suggest to make it better. I thought to put 2 bytes "headers" and 2 bytes "Lenght" per package that I will write. In this way, I can determine where my data packets start and end while reading.

Comment: The typical way I would serialize an list is `writer.Write(list.Count); list.Foreach(writer.Write);` That way you know the number of items when deserializing. If you have 2d data you would need height & width instead of just count.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH I'll try the way you mentioned, I'll share if I am successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was so simple that I don't know how I missed it. The array type I defined during reading is `integer`, but my data is `short`. When the data type of the array was `short` the whole problem was gone.

I also solved the total number of sequences in the file as follows.

The lengths of the 2-dimensional array at the time of writing are 48 * 64. I divided the total number of bytes in the file by 48 * 64. Also, since my data is `short` (`2 bytes`) I divided it by 2 to get the total number of strings.

```
var arrayCount = readBinary.BaseStream.Length / (48*64) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but to show you another approach since you are using unsafe and know the size and dimensions of the array. So I give you a minimal allocation, generic pointer span based constant multi dimensional multi array reader and writer

**Given**

```
public static unsafe void Write<T>(T[,] source, Stream stream) where T : unmanaged
{
   fixed (void* asd = source)
      stream.Write(new Span<byte>(asd, source.Length * sizeof(T)));
}
public static unsafe bool Read<T>(T[,] source, Stream stream) where T : unmanaged
{
   fixed (void* asd = source)
      return stream.Read(new Span<byte>(asd, source.Length * sizeof(T))) != 0;
}
```

**The worlds most contrived example**

```
var array = new short[,] {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

using (var rs = new FileStream(@"D:\test.dat", FileMode.Create))
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      array[0, 0] = (short) i; // to prove its working
      Write(array, rs);
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array.Cast<short>()));
   }

Console.WriteLine();

using (var ws = new FileStream(@"D:\test.dat", FileMode.Open))
   while (Read(array, ws))
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array.Cast<short>())); // to prove its working
```

**Output**

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

<sub>***Note** : you can modify this to create and return an array. however this was just a low allocation version that can reuse an array*</sub>

<sub>***Note** : if you just write 2 ints before the array, you can read any size array and any amount packets*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm getting a missing reference error for command new Span <>. Can you direct which reference should I include?

Comment: @saklanmaz You seem to be stuck in the olden days, with .net framework :) upgrade to core or .net5

Comment: Unfortunately :). Since the project is an old project, I am afraid that different problems may arise with the upgrade. However, I will try to share in an empty project. I mark it as the answer for taking your time. Although my solution is not very healthy, it can work at the initial stage. Friends who encounter such a problem can take care of both. :)